# Нужно чтоб один многотабличный запрос возвращал и результат, количество строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос, который возвращает значение с 2-х таблиц, которые отвечают некоторому условию, нужно сделать так что б запрос также возвращал количество записей которые отвечают условию, собственно сам запрос :

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.speciality, c.level, c.email, c.skype, c.city, 
    s.status_type, c.status_id, c.linkedin, c.link_cv, c.interview_res, c.createdAt,
    c.updatedAt, c.recruiter_id, u.first_name AS fname, u.last_name AS lname
FROM
    Candidates c
    JOIN Users u 
        ON c.recruiter_id = u.id
    JOIN Statuses s
        ON s.id = c.status_id
WHERE
    c.deleted = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку MySQL не поддерживает оконных функций и общих табличных выражений, не вижу другого способа, кроме повторения всего запроса:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.speciality, c.level, c.email, c.skype, c.city, 
    s.status_type, c.status_id, c.linkedin, c.link_cv, c.interview_res, c.createdAt,
    c.updatedAt, c.recruiter_id, u.first_name AS fname, u.last_name AS lname
,(SELECT count(*)
FROM
    Candidates c
    JOIN Users u 
        ON c.recruiter_id = u.id
    JOIN Statuses s
        ON s.id = c.status_id
WHERE
    c.deleted = false) cnt
FROM
    Candidates c
    JOIN Users u 
        ON c.recruiter_id = u.id
    JOIN Statuses s
        ON s.id = c.status_id
WHERE
    c.deleted = false
```

Я плохо знаю MySQL.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что искал.

Comment: Кстати, уже и оконные функции, и СТЕ, поддерживаются в MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что понял правильно вопрос, но может так:

```html
SELECT
    c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.speciality, c.level, c.email, c.skype, c.city, 
    s.status_type, c.status_id, c.linkedin, c.link_cv, c.interview_res, c.createdAt,
    c.updatedAt, c.recruiter_id, u.first_name AS fname, u.last_name AS lname, count(*)
FROM
    Candidates c
    JOIN Users u 
        ON c.recruiter_id = u.id
    JOIN Statuses s
        ON s.id = c.status_id
WHERE
    c.deleted = false
GROUP by c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.speciality, c.level, c.email, c.skype, c.city, 
    s.status_type, c.status_id, c.linkedin, c.link_cv, c.interview_res, c.createdAt,
    c.updatedAt, c.recruiter_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
```